# How to obtain the explicit solution of the following integral equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, integral-equations

I'm considering the following integral equation 
$$
f(x,y,z)=x+\int_0^x\int_0^y\int_0^z f(u,v,w) dudvdw 
$$
It seems that 
$$
f(x,y,z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{n+1} y^n z^n}{(n+1)!n!n!} 
$$
is the solution. How to transform it into a closed form instead of a series?

Comment: $\partial f / \partial x$ is a function of $xyz$, and I wonder what is the "closed form" of it you expect to find (in the two-variable case it would be [$I_0(\sqrt{2xy})$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1)).